# Efficient way to refactor a switch with object's

Tags: javascript

I have this switch:

```
  const getTimeframeUnits = ({ value }) => {
    switch (value) {
      case 'day':
        return setTimeframe({
          value: 24,
          subtractUnit: 'hours',
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: { hour: 'hA' },
          unitStepSize: 2,
          formatUnit: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'
        });
      case 'week':
        return setTimeframe({
          value: 1,
          subtractUnit: 'weeks',
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: { day: 'MMM D' },
          unitStepSize: 1,
          formatUnit: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
      case 'month':
        return setTimeframe({
          value: 1,
          subtractUnit: 'months',
          unit: 'day',
          displayFormats: { day: 'MMM D' },
          unitStepSize: 1,
          formatUnit: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
      case 'year':
        return setTimeframe({
          value: 1,
          subtractUnit: 'years',
          unit: 'month',
          displayFormats: { month: 'MMM YYYY' },
          unitStepSize: 1,
          formatUnit: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        });
      default:
        return setTimeframe({
          value: 24,
          subtractUnit: 'hours',
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: { hour: 'hA' },
          unitStepSize: 2,
          formatUnit: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH'
        });
    }
  };
```

And just by looking it hurts because it seems too big.. How I can make it smaller and at the same time, faster?

`setTimeframe` is a simple state from React.